# How to move the caret to the end of line in the VS2010 with Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, coderush

I'm using Vs2010 and ReSharper 6.

When I enter the string with quotation,then I press the ENTER.

The "+" is displayed at end of line,and the new quotation has appeared.

I hope NO "+" and a pair of quotation appeared. Could you help me?

oh,I have installed CodeRush within VS2010.The CodeRush and ReSharper conflict?

Comment: The behaviour you describe is not familiar to me as something ReSharper does, so I suspect it may be a CodeRush thing. In general, I would say having both of them running is asking for trouble.

Comment: Maybe,I think so too. But before install ReSharper,the Enter key's behaviour when the caret within the string,it's normal.

Answer (score 5):

You can use smart completion Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then R# will add a semi-colon and move to the next line.